# Generate random number from set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

You are given a set T of n non negative real numbers ${t_0, t_1 ... t_n}$ and probabilities $p_0,p_1...p_n$ where $\sum\limits_{i}^{n} p_1 = 1$. Assume $t_0 < t_1 ...< t_n$. Given a random number generator that produces values in [0,1] uniformly, how would you generate a value X from T according to the specified probabilities?

PS- This is not a homework problem

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $X$ is your random number, then $P(x\in[0,p_0])=p_0$; P$(X\in(p_0,p_0+p_1])=p_1$; $P(X\in(p_0+p_1,p_0+p_1+p_2])=p_2$, etc.